# setting start urls for scrapy outside of class

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new Scrapy, how can I pass `start_urls` from outside of the class,
I tried to make `start_urls` outside of class but it didn't work.What I am trying to do is to create a file with file name from dictionary (`search_dict`) and value of it as a start url for Scrapy

```
search_dict={'hello world':'https://www.google.com/search?q=hello+world',
            'my code':'https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+questions',
            'test':'https://www.google.com/search?q="test"'}

class googlescraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    #start_urls= ??
    found_items = []
    def parse:
        item=dict()
        #code here
        self.found_items.append(item)

for k,v in search_dict.items():
    with open(k,'w') as csvfile:
        process = CrawlerProcess({
            'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0,
            'LOG_LEVEL': 'DEBUG',
            'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT':30,})
        process.crawl(googlescraper) #scrapy spider needs start url
        spider = next(iter(process.crawlers)).spider
        process.start()
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(spider.found_items)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Scrapy documentation has an example of instantiating a crawler with arguments: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spider-arguments

You could pass in your urls in something like:

```py
# ...

class GoogleScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    # ...
    # Omit `start_urls` in the class definition
    # ...

process.crawl(GoogleScraper, start_urls=[
    # The URL you want to pass here
])
```

The `kwargs` in the call to `process.crawl()` will be passed to the spider initializer. The default initializer will copy any `kwargs` as attributes of the spider class. So this is equivalent as setting `start_urls` in the class definition.

Relevant section in Scrapy docs: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess.crawl

Comment: it works, another related question so any definitions before parse can be put in process.crawl(...) i.e in my example allowed_domains,found_items,name ?

Comment: Yes, they will be set as attributes on the scraper class.